# Invisible Window with visible components

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm looking for a way to use a image as a Window, or, at least, in appearance.
The most logical solution seems to be using a invisible Window with visible components.
Google offers me two solutions :
The awful one : take a screenshot of what is under the Window and use it as a background while making the Window undecorated.
The "on its way to be official" one : use AWTUtilities to make the Window transparent. Cool, but doesn't work with IcedTea or Linux (I didn't try the official JRE on Linux yet).

Is there any other way to achieve the same result (using AWT or Swing) ?

Comment: Now that Java 7 is out, you may want to try the official updated APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the quick answer to window transparency at least is no (unless someone wants to prove me wrong, which I would love!) Screenshots may work better than you think though if the contents of the window aren't changing much.

The AWTUtilities method (or the same thing in the official API from Java 7 onwards) requires hardware acceleration which prohibits it from working 100% reliably across all platforms, so it's not guaranteed to necessarily work even on all Windows boxes.

Comment: seems to work fine for me with XP at least...also http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2007/02/non-rectangular-windows-update.html might be useful